# React-Select custom value container

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am using react select for people picker, and I have an interface for my props to pass

this is ModuleA.tsx

```
    customLoadOptions?: Function,
```

```
const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return <components.ValueContainer {...props}>test{children}</components.ValueContainer>
};
export const PeoplePicker = (props: PeoplePickerIProps) => {
    const { customComponents } = props;
    const components = customComponents ? { customComponents } : { ValueContainer }
...
...
...
<AsyncSelect
     components={components}
...
...
```

and lets say ModuleB.tsx

```
const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return  <components.ValueContainer {...props}>test2</components.ValueContainer>
};

return (
    <PeoplePicker components={ValueContainer}...
)
```

yet my custom component won't work but the default one (not the one I wrote in my people picker component but the react-select default)

although, if I apply this method in ModuleA, it works

am I missing something?

Comment: the long and the short of it, I want to use components API from different module

Comment: I solved my problem with formatOptionLabel, though still would be good to know if I could learn anything